# Moving contents of RAX to C variable (x86-64 asm)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

This is a rather naive question. I'm just playing around with allocating some executable memory and manually assembling some x86 code to run in it. I'm a bit confused by how addressing works in 64-bit mode. If I have a variable in my C code, and I want to move the contents of RAX into this variable, which form of the MOV instruction should I use? (This isn't using inline assembly, so I can't get the compiler to do it for me; I just have the value of &var to play with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Intel syntax, it will be something like `mov [var],rax`, where `var` is basically the 64-bit immediate address.

I think this what Intel call `MOV moffs64*,RAX` in "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual".

Comment: Great thanks. And by the looks of it this is only possible with RAX and a small number of other registers?

Comment: It seems that this form is RAX-only (in 64 bits anyhow).

Comment: Nathan, how would the instruction be encoded? Opcodes A2-A3 are specific to the accumulator, and I don't see any way of doing this using REX.W + 89, since AFAIK it's not possible to have a 64-bit displacement.

Comment: FWIW, yasm accepts "MOV [qword 0x0], RAX" but rejects "MOV [qword 0x0], RDX"