# Error C2403 using inline x86 C++ assembly moving register contents to variable

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly, visual-studio-2015, inline-assembly

I've worked with the inline assembler before, but I'm getting an error I haven't seen before and can't seem to find around the interwebs. The closest I've gotten is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383691/move-register-value-into-an-array) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318816/moving-contents-of-rax-to-c-variable-x86-64-asm) but neither have helped. The error is when moving the contents of the EAX register to a variable dx. It seems to me it should just be the below, and in fact disassembly generates the same code as I wrote, but I get two errors:

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
         auto x1 = 10, x2 = 2, dx = 0;
         __asm{
              MOV EAX, DWORD PTR [x1]
              SUB EAX, DWORD PTR [x2]
              MOV DWORD PTR [dx], EAX
              ;error C2403: 'dx': register must be base/index in 'first operand'
              ;error C2415: improper operand type

              ;Disassembly generated the following
              mov eax,dword ptr[x1]
              sub eax,dword ptr[x2]
              mov dword ptr[dx],eax
        }
    }
```

I don't think I need to use a different register and I thought that MOV could move contents of a register into a variable like this. Oddly, the following line is exactly the same but using y1, y2, and dy, and generates no error. I've tried just using [dx] to the same result, and by now I can only think of something like MMX instructions, which seems unnecessary. Thanks for your help in advance!

Side-note: Is there a preference to all-caps versus lowercase when writing in x86 (or any) assembly language?

[Edit] Now I'm curious, how can it generate assembly code using dword ptr [dx] if my using of it confused the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DX is a 16-bit x86 general purpose register in its own right and the assembler is getting confused by your syntax (hence 'register must be base/index in first operand'--what would, for example, `dword ptr [ax]` mean?). Choose a different name for your variable.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot about that. Thank you for saving me from another hour of head-scratching!